# measuring image similarity with opencv

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

At my company we print out documents, make changes to those documents, and scan them back in. Sometimes the scans are subtly rotated and I use OpenCV to align the two images. Here's the code I use to do this:

```
import sys
import cv2
import numpy as np

if len(sys.argv) != 4:
  print('USAGE')
  print('  python3 align.py ref.png new.png output.png')
  sys.exit()

FLANN_INDEX_LSH    = 6

def filter_matches(kp1, kp2, matches, ratio = 0.75):
  mkp1, mkp2 = [], []
  for m in matches:
    if len(m) == 2 and m[0].distance < m[1].distance * ratio:
      m = m[0]
      mkp1.append( kp1[m.queryIdx] )
      mkp2.append( kp2[m.trainIdx] )
  p1 = np.float32([kp.pt for kp in mkp1])
  p2 = np.float32([kp.pt for kp in mkp2])
  kp_pairs = zip(mkp1, mkp2)
  return p1, p2, list(kp_pairs)

def alignImages(im1, im2):
  detector = cv2.AKAZE_create()
  flann_params= dict(algorithm = FLANN_INDEX_LSH,
    table_number = 6, # 12
    key_size = 12,     # 20
    multi_probe_level = 1) #2
  matcher = cv2.FlannBasedMatcher(flann_params, {})

  kp1, desc1 = detector.detectAndCompute(im1, None)
  kp2, desc2 = detector.detectAndCompute(im2, None)

  raw_matches = matcher.knnMatch(desc1, trainDescriptors = desc2, k = 2)
  p1, p2, kp_pairs = filter_matches(kp1, kp2, raw_matches)
  if len(p1) < 4:
    print('%d matches found, not enough for homography estimation' % len(p1))
    sys.exit()

  H, matches = cv2.findHomography(p1, p2, cv2.RANSAC, 5.0)
  # the larger the number the better
  print(str(len(matches.ravel().tolist())));

  height, width = im2.shape

  imResult = cv2.warpPerspective(im1, H, (width, height))

  return imResult
  
refFilename = sys.argv[1]
imFilename = sys.argv[2]
outFilename = sys.argv[3]

imRef = cv2.imread(refFilename, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
im = cv2.imread(imFilename, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

imNew = alignImages(im, imRef)

cv2.imwrite(outFilename, imNew)
```

The problem is that sometimes the documents are a complete mismatch. eg.

[image]

When I try to run the above script two completely mismatched pages I get something like this:

[image]

My question is...  is there a way I can detect these completely mismatched pages? Is there a way to score two different pages by similarity? I had that `print(str(len(matches.ravel().tolist())))` might do the trick (it's in the code) but sometimes two mismatched pages can have more matches then correctly matched pages, in my experience. If memory serves, one of the image alignment / object recognition methods kinda scores each match so maybe if I could do that with AKAZE I could score the pages by the ratio of number matches with a confidence > 20% vs the number of matches with a confidence of < 20%? But if that were a viable strategy how would I do that with AKAZE?

Comment: crosspost: https://forum.opencv.org/t/measuring-image-similarity-with-opencv/14208

Comment: Maybe one of these methods could help determine if the images are similar enough to be matches?  https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/d93/group__img__hash.html